# How do you write a policy for "canDeleteComment" on post through Laravel Authorization?

Tags: php, laravel, return, authorization, conditional-statements

I have posts, the posts have comments.
What I need to do is authorize both the comment author and the post author to delete a comment on the same post.
Idea is the author of the post being commented is able to delete unwanted comments from his posts and the author of the comments is also able to delete the comments he left.
I see you can pass multiple variables to the `Gate` facade.
So I'm thinking I can write the policy like this:

```
    class CommentPolicy
    {
        public function deleteComment(User $user, Comment $comment, Post $post)
        {        
            //mumbo jumbo goes here
        }

    }
```

But ok, what do you put in the logic part of that policy?
I was thinking maybe this:

```
return ($user->id === $comment->user_id || $user->id === $post->user_id);
```

or maybe:

```
$check =  array ($user->id === $comment->user_id,  $user->id === $post->user_id);

        if (($check[0] = 0) && ($check[1] = 0)){

            return 0;

        }else{

            return 1;
        }
```

but is this legit? I mean can php return values this way? And if not how do you check these conditions?

Comment: What exactly is your question? And your first approach seems correct to me

Comment: I am asking how should I write the policy, however now I am facing a new problem. I tried to add a `@can('deleteComment', $c, $i)` in my blade view inside a loop, where $c is the comment and $i is the post but I get this error: Argument 3 passed to App\Policies\CommentPolicy::deleteComment() must be an instance of App\Post, none given

Comment: deleteComment takes 3 arguments, but you're only passing 2 (Comment and Post). Pass your User as 1st argument

Comment: You don't need to pass the user. The user is automatically checked as the auth user. Besides I already found the solution. You have to pass the comment and post as an array [$c, $i] , oh and the first way for checking is the correct one. But what are You referring to exactly? Passing where?